# Tabular and tabu environment problems

Tags: longtable, longtabu, adjustwidth

I am using `tabular` environment for long time and it gives me good results as overflowing problem of tabular environment can be managed using `\adjustbox` command. But problem with tabular is it can not span on multiple pages. So I tried `longtable` and `longtabu` environments. These environments span the table to multiple pages but overflow the page width in case of wide tables and nothing like `\adjustwidth` or `\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth` seems to work.

Here problem is each environment has one-one feature I need and not both, so how can I combine both features into one?

PS: Please post example codes after testing.

Comment: well, usually provide a code who ask, we only help her/him where she/he stuck ... use of `\adjustbox` is desperate action of last resort when other measures doesn't help. (so don't use it). Use `tabu` is fragile, since package is not maintained and baggy. I believe that use `logtable` is just fine ...

Comment: if you are needing to scale tables with adjustbox and similar then something is wrong, it should be able to make them fit within the page without resorting to such a tool, which should only be used as a last resort.   As for your PS, it is up to you, asking the question, to post the test document.